# Php and mySql Join or loop or what?

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have the following code, and database. My intent is the end user can select the colums from a database (by 'ajax'ing option/selects direct from mysql) and run a report on them. I can predetermine the tables they use, they pick the columns.
my biggest problem is the BEST way to perform a 'schedule' query.

To run a schedule i need the Details from 'Customer' and 'Delivery' - (customer info and delivery address) and i use the 'custnum' from all tables, plus the year, to choose which yearly schedule to run - ie custnum bar12345 - yearly schedule table is bar123452012

there could be 2 products per 'custnum' pulled from the bar123452012 table.

this table is just a single row per product, but 367 columns, 1- prodid, and 366 titled with the 
yday
 integer. php works out if it needs to use 365 or 366 in that year in a different function.

What would you suggest? A php loop to pull all customers one by one and format in a table, or is there an SQL query that will Left Join a different table to each row based on the tindex . 2012id?! 
need speed and efficiency as we are talking at least 200 customer tables, maybe up to 1000.

Thanks to Dwurf for a reality check. Reorganised database to have one schedule table, and work from that.

Thanks Dwurf. New design being worked on all afternoon...  Database

Table structure for table customer

custnum varchar(255)    No
surname varchar(50) No
name    varchar(50) No
phone1  varchar(50) No
phone2  varchar(50) No
email   varchar(50) No
add1    varchar(50) No
add2    varchar(50) No
city    varchar(50) No
postcode    varchar(10) No

Table structure for table deliverydetails

special varchar(50) No
add1    varchar(50) No
add2    varchar(50) No
city    varchar(50) No
postcode    varchar(10) No
custnum varchar(100)    No

Table structure for table notes

custnum varchar(50) No
notes   varchar(50) No
time    timestamp   No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Table structure for table prodgroups

pgroup  varchar(20) No
name    varchar(50) No
description varchar(50) No

Table structure for table products

name    varchar(50) No
quantity    varchar(50) No
description varchar(50) No
pgroup  varchar(50) No
price   varchar(50) No
picture varchar(100)    No
productid   varchar(10) No
suppid  varchar(50) No
vat tinyint(1)  No

Table structure for table schedule

productid   varchar(15) No

d0  varchar(100)    No
d1  varchar(100)    Yes NULL
d2  varchar(100)    Yes NULL
.......
d362    varchar(100)    Yes NULL
d363    varchar(100)    Yes NULL
d364    varchar(100)    Yes NULL
d365    varchar(100)    Yes NULL

custnum varchar(50) No

id  int(50) No

Table structure for table suppliers

suppid  varchar(50) No
name    varchar(50) No
phone1  int(100)    No
phone2  int(100)    No
email   varchar(100)    No
add1    varchar(50) No
add2    varchar(50) No
city    varchar(50) No
postcode    varchar(10) No
description varchar(100)    No

Table structure for table vatgroups

vat int(20) No
amount  decimal(20,0)   No
description varchar(20) No

Comment: I recommend rethinking how you want to attack this problem. My first question is...what are you trying to do? What kind of annual schedule are you trying to construct and for what purpose? At the end of the day, what will you have?

Comment: The end result will be a 'delivery calendar' - A report/table with customer1 name, delivery address , c1.product1name  day1, day2... day 365 the c1.product2 name, d1 d2... (or as many/few days as needed at the time) then the next row will be the next customer prod1,prod2...  My issue is i need a separate table for each customers schedule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would you suggest? A php loop to pull all customers one by one and format in a table,

This approach is suicidal for performance

> or is there an SQL query that will Left Join a different table to each row based on the tindex . 2012id?!

This isn't really possible with the design you outline in your question. A design change might help though: if you have a single table for all of your reports and you add a column for the report name you will be a bit closer. Consider something like:

```
Table structure for table Reports
custnum varchar(255) No
productid   varchar(15) No  
date  DateTime    No
```

Now you can construct a query to grab all rows for a particular customer

```
select * from Reports 
where date between '2012-01-01' and '2013-01-01'
and custnum = 'bob54326'
```

Use PHP (or whatever you're using) to generate the table from these results.

I know this strategy breaks your 'direct table access from UI' model, but I'm afraid that model simply doesn't work very well. Change your design to work with the tools you have instead of trying to force the tools to conform to your design.

Comment: I can understand this approach, however i would have preferred to keep the tables seperate rather than have a larger table that will need optimisation regularly, as an UPDATE to each would be occurring more often than the reporting. If this is the only option to get this kind of a report/query then i will have to do this. Thanks for answering though! Phil.

Comment: also 300 customers, 2 products per customer, after 1 year i would have 600 rows, but 220000 total values in one table. 1000 customers is 730000 total values in 2000 rows. Would this start to cause a problem?

Comment: No, less than 1 million rows will fly on modern databases. Larger tables will still be fine but require a bit more care in design and maintenance.

Comment: Wow reading back to some questions from a few years ago, makes me facepalm with some of the ways I'd decided to do things.